# Unable to export module in another file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create some dummy function in nodejs and trying to export it in another file but when I am running it using `node index.js` it might some sort of silly mistake but its showing error that:

```
TypeError: spr.comb is not a function
```

Below is my code:

**spread.js**

```
const comb = () => {
   const arr = [4,5,6];
   const newArr = [1,2,3,...arr];
   console.log(newArr);
}

module.exports = comb;
```

**index.js**

```
const spr =  require('./spread');
spr.comb();
```

Someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I dont think `spr.comb()` is right. the `spr` has the `comb` reference. just do `spr()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you have completely overwritten the `module.exports` object.

`module.exports` is an empty object to which you can add the values to export from a module.

In your case, you have re-assigned the `module.exports` to `comb` function. So, to call the function, change

```
spr.comb();
```

to

```
spr();
```

For `spr.comb()` to work, you need to export the `comb` function as shown below:

```
module.exports.comb = comb;
```

or

```
exports.comb = { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this(in spread.js):

```
const comb = module.exports.comb = () => {
const arr = [4, 5, 6];
const newArr = [1, 2, 3, ...arr];
console.log(newArr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't use a user defined name here because you have exported comb from your spread file

```
const spr =  require('./spread'); 
spr.comb();
```

Use this instead

```
const comb = require('./spread');
```

If you want to use custom name you need to modify your spread file like this

```
module.exports = () => {
   const arr = [4,5,6];
   const newArr = [1,2,3,...arr];
   console.log(newArr);
}
```

Now you are exporting a function from spread, while importing/ including it in index.js you can provide a custom name to this function.

```
const {custom name comes here}=  require('./spread');
```

For Example

```
const comb = require('./spread');
const myCombFn = require('./spread');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is not a default export you would need to surround it with curly braces in your main file like so:

```
const {spr} =  require('./spread');
spr.comb();
```